# Is there a way to shorten my python code?

Tags: python

So my code does what I want it to do, but I'm SURE there's a way shorter way to do it, where you can grab the prices associated with the input immediately. I'm just not sure how to do it, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sbEF.png) are the original instructions!

```
service1 = 'Oil change'
service2 = 'Tire rotation'
service3 = 'Car wash'

name1 = 'oil change'
name2 = 'tire rotation'
name3 = 'car wash'

price1 = 35
price2 = 19
price3 = 7

auto_service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')

if auto_service in service1:
    print('You entered: {}'.format(service1))
    print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(name1, price1))

elif auto_service in service2:
    print('You entered: {}'.format(service2))
    print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(name2, price2))

elif auto_service in service3:
    print('You entered: {}'.format(service3))
    print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(name3, price3))

else:
    print('You entered: {}'.format(auto_service))
    print('Error: Requested service is not recognized')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Code review is _off-topic_ here, but try posting on our sister site [codereview.se]. (Make sure to take _its_ tour as well before you post.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a dict with service-price pairs.

```
services = {
    'oil change': 35,
    'tire rotation': 19,
    'car wash': 7,
    }
```

I'll let you figure out how to implement it, since this is homework, but here's a snippet to get you started at least: `if auto_service.lower() in services:`

Answer (score 1):

```
prices = {
    'Oil change': 35,
    'Tire rotation': 19,
    'Car wash': 7,
}

service = input('Enter desired auto service: ')
print(f"You entered: {service}")
try:
    print(f"Cost of {service}: ${prices[service]}")
except KeyError:
    print(f"Error: requested service is not recognized")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
services = ['Oil change', 'Tire rotation', 'Car wash']
prices = [35, 19, 7]

auto_service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')

print("Cost:", prices[services.index(auto_service)])
```

You can store the data in a `list`, and use `.index()` to get the corresponding value from another list.

**Note:** If you give a value that is not in the list, it will throw `ValueError`. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to fix.

Comment: It's easier to use a dict than parallel lists. See my answer and [Samwise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719610/4518341) for examples.

Comment: @wjandrea, I know. Just leaving this around if the OP has’t studied dictionaries yet. Obviously, dict is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
services = [ {'name': 'oil change',    'price': 35},
             {'name': 'tire rotation', 'price': 19},
             {'name': 'car wash',      'price': 7 } ]

auto_service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')

for service in services:
    if auto_service.lower() in service['name']:
        print('You entered: {}'.format(service['name']))
        print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(service['name'], service['price']))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:-

```
service = ('Oil change','Tire rotation','Car wash')
name = ('oil change','tire rotation','car wash')
price = (35,19,7)
auto_service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')
if auto_service in service:
    pos=service.index(auto_service)
    print('You entered: {}'.format(auto_service))
    print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(name[pos], price[pos]))
else:
    print('You entered: {}'.format(auto_service))
    print('Error: Requested service is not recognized')
```

Comment: You can remove the "name" tuple as it doesn't possess any important information/

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary - and store the data in it; you don't need 3 variables per item - you need one.

```
services = {'Oil change':('oil change', 35),
            'Tire rotation':('tire rotation',19),
            'Car wash':('car wash', 7), }

auto_service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')

item = services.get(auto_service, None)
if item
   print('You entered: {}'.format(auto_service))
   print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(item[0], item[1]))
else:
   print('You entered: {}'.format(auto_service))
   print('Error: Requested service is not recognized')
```

Comment: Where the first item in the tuple is just the lowercase version of the key, it's not necessary. You can just convert the key to lowercase.

Comment: That is true - but I wanted to replicate closely what the OP had - where the line item (with the price) had the option of being a different string.

Comment: @wjandrea how would i convert the key to lowercase?

Comment: @draeway it's a string, so simply `key.lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for your problem. A lot of the other responses on this page are good too.

```
'''Beaufuh
Follow me on twitter @beaufuhh
'''
#define a dictionary of services.
services = {
    'Oil change': 35,
    'Tire rotation': 19,
    'Car wash': 7
}
#ask the customer what they want to have performed. 
auto_service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')
#repeat their selection
print('You entered: {}'.format(auto_service))
#if the user's desired auot service is in the services dictionary, print price
if auto_service in services.keys():
    print('{} is ${} dollars.'.format(auto_service.lower(), services.get(auto_service)))
#else the user's desired auto service is not in the services dictioanry, print we do not sell that here. sorry about that.
else:
    print('We do not sell that here. Sorry about that!')
```

Comment: I would have used get (with a default of None - saves a double hit on the dictionary), but it is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using get but it didn't make sense with the output of the program that this guy wanted.

Comment: If you look at my answer (v similar to yours) as to how get can work - just use None as the default - None will never be in the dictioary - and then test against None.

Also you don't ever need to do : ``auto_service in services.keys()`` - ``auto_service in services`` would be just as good - and probably a bit quicker.